# RedBeanPHP slow R::exportAll()

Tags: php, postgresql, performance, redbean

I am using RedBeanPHP to connect to a Postgres database, but I am experiencing slow query times for otherwise simple queries. This appears to be related to RedBean's `exportAll()`. I am accessing similar to RedBean's example:

```
$books = R::findAll( 'book' );
$beans= R::exportAll( $books );
```

Using the query directly with:

```
$rows = R::getAll($sql);
$books = R::convertToBeans('books', $rows);
$beans= R::exportAll( $books );
```

This query takes about 1.25 seconds on a table with only 66, with two mapped tables (that are linked in RedBean). This query time seems very slow and directly related to R::exportAll().

Versions:

- RedBeanPHP = 4.3.3
- PostgreSQL = 9.6.2
- PHP = 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4
- OS = Ubuntu

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a ton of research I found a blurb in the ['duplicate' section of the RedBeanPHP website](http://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/duplicate) describing the following:

> Both dup() and exportAll() need to query the database schema which is
>   slow. To speed up the process you can pass a database schema:
>
> ```
> R::$duplicationManager->setTables( $schema ); To obtain the schema use:
>
> $schema = R::$duplicationManager->getSchema(); You can now use this schema to feed it to setTables(). R::duplicate() and
> ```
>
> R::exportAll() both use this schema.

Which is exactly what I experienced, but I was unable to access `R::$duplicationManager->getSchema()` due to $duplicationManager now being a private variable ([Found here in the API](http://www.redbeanphp.com/api/source-class-RedBeanPHP.Facade.html#81)).

Luckily there is a 'getDuplicationManager()' function further down in the API documentation so with great success:

```
$schema = R::getDuplicationManager()->getSchema();
R::getDuplicationManager()->setTables($schema);
```

This brought my time down to ~0.14 seconds, which is far more reasonable.

Comment: Also, I added this schema set directly after my `R::setup();` and `R::freeze(true);` initialization. I know I was a little concerned about where to put these calls, but with your RedBean setup only happening once, there should only be a need to set your schema once. 

** Unless perhaps, you switch databases. **